# MSDN C# ProcessController Sample

Tags: c#, msdn, sample

I've found this MSDN article that explains how to monitor processes and services with C#:

[ProcessController Sample: Demonstrates Processes and Services Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645519(VS.71).aspx)

However, I can't download or find this sample anywhere! And it would be really helpful.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found it!

This ProcessController sample is part of the Microsoft Visual Studio .NET, version 7.0.

I was able to download it from [VisualStudio .NET Help Documentation Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=41c68033-775c-4d92-a9c4-2db8e8238f37&DisplayLang=en).

Comment: I dont see C# sample in the link. It only has VB sample. Can you help me get to C# sample.

Comment: After googling a bit, I found a mirror which hosts the C# version : http://www.pudn.com/downloads6/sourcecode/windows/detail21404_en.html

Comment: Thanks @Nitin. That's a great link.

Answer (score 2):

The information you are looking for is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9hsy596(VS.80).aspx

You need to install the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK v2.0 which comes with the QuickStart samples.

In response to your comment:

I downloaded from [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FE6F2099-B7B4-4F47-A244-C96D69C35DEC&displaylang=en).  I then ran `setup.exe` and on the page titled **Installation Options** I checked the **QuickStart Samples** box and completed the installation.  I then followed the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9hsy596(VS.80).aspx) to access the QuickStarts on my system.

Comment: I've installed it, but still don't find this sample.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I've followed your steps, but still couldn't find the sample I'm looking for (ProcessController).
Could you find it in your installed samples?